# How to get "location" UIToolbar button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uitoolbar, cllocationmanager

I was looking to add a "locate" button similar to the one in Apple's Map app.

[image]

`^There`

I looked in the options for bordered buttons but it's not listed.  How can I add one of these?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create it yourself.

For example, using this method of `UIBarButtonItem`:

```
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image style:(UIBarButtonItemStyle)style target:(id)target action:(SEL)action
```